# Question regarding dependence of two random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am having trouble understanding a problem. A continuous random variable $X$ is given, and then another random variable $Z$ is defined as a function of the cumulative distribution of $X$. Let's say that $F_X$ denotes cumulative distribution of $X$, i.e. $F(x)=\operatorname{P}(X\le x)$ and now define $Z=e^{F(X)}$

So how exactly do we interpret this. What is the distribution $G$ of $Z$. We have $G(z)=\operatorname{P}(Z\le z)=\operatorname{P}(e^{F(X)}\le z)=\operatorname{P}(F(X)\le \log z)?=\operatorname{P}(\operatorname{P}(X\le x)\le \log z)$ or does it mean $\operatorname{P}(\operatorname{P}(X\le z)\le \log z)$ (the first one does not seem likely), or something else. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

**EDIT:** Thank you for the three answers. So as far as I understand we just have to take inverse of $F$ (those of *Yujie Zha* and *spaceisdarkgreen* imply this). So we have $\operatorname{P}(e^{F(X)}\le z)=\operatorname{P}(F(X)\le \log z)=\operatorname{P}(X\le F^{-1}(\log z))=F(F^{-1}(\log z))=\log z$. This must be correct now, right? However there is still something unclear for me - it seems like Z is independant of X (I mean has nothing to do with X)

Comment: Did u mean $\le$ rather than $\lt$ in $\operatorname{P}(e^{F(X)}<z)$?

Answer (score 2):

So to make it clear:

Take probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr A, \mathbb P)$.

We have random variable (r.v.) $X: \Omega \mapsto \mathbb R$. Distribution $F: \mathbb R \mapsto [0,1]$ is monotone.

Define $f: \mathbb R \mapsto \mathbb R$ (monotone as well):
$$f(x) = e^{F(x)}, x \in \mathbb R$$

And then $Z$ is another r.v. defined as

$$Z: \Omega \mapsto \mathbb R, Z=f \circ X$$
$$Z(\omega)=f\circ X(\omega)=f(X(\omega)), \forall \omega \in \Omega$$

Thus
$$G(z) = \mathbb P(\{\omega: Z(\omega) \le z\})$$$$=\mathbb P(\{\omega: f\circ X(\omega) \le z\})$$$$=\mathbb P(\{\omega: X(\omega) \le f^{-1}(z)\})$$

Answer (score 1):

$F(X) \neq P(X \le x)$.

$F(X)$ is a distribution. (Take distribution $X$ and apply function $F$ to the outcomes).

Detailed explanation:

The notation $f(X)$ for some function $f$ and random variable $X$ can be considered an '[abuse of notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuse_of_notation)' as it applies $f$ to each of the outcomes of $X$ rather than to $X$ itself (thinking carefully about what the domain of $f$ consists of should avoid this confusion).

Mathematicians often write $f(S)$ on some set $S$ to represent the set $\{f(s) \,|\, s \in S\}$ and the same thing is happening here with the outcomes of the random variable X.

After $f$ is applied, the new outcomes still retain their original probabilities and this creates a new random variable.

Note that $f$ has to be well defined in order for this to work (ie. $f$ needs to be injective on the outcomes of $X$).

Example:

Let $X$ be the result of a fair dice roll.

You might represent $X$ with something like $(1 \rightarrow \frac{1}{6},2 \rightarrow \frac{1}{6},3 \rightarrow \frac{1}{6},4 \rightarrow \frac{1}{6},5 \rightarrow \frac{1}{6},6 \rightarrow \frac{1}{6})$. For the cdf, we have $F(x)=\frac{x}{6}$.

Now, $F(X)$ is a random variable where the outcomes are $\frac{\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}}{6}=\{\frac{1}{6},\frac{2}{6},\frac{3}{6},\frac{4}{6},\frac{5}{6},\frac{6}{6}\}$. The outcomes retain their original probability of $\frac{1}{6}$ so you have $(\frac{1}{6} \rightarrow \frac{1}{6},\frac{2}{6} \rightarrow \frac{1}{6},\frac{3}{6} \rightarrow \frac{1}{6},\frac{4}{6} \rightarrow \frac{1}{6},\frac{5}{6} \rightarrow \frac{1}{6},\frac{6}{6} \rightarrow \frac{1}{6})$

---

Going back to $G(z)=P(e^{F(X)} \le z)$, if $F$ is invertible, then you can rearrange it so $G(z)=P(X \le F^{-1}(\log z))$ which would probably be a helpful rearrangement.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly interpret $F(X)$ as a random variable. After all, $F(x) = P(X\le x)$ is a function and a function of a random variable is a random variable. It's true that a naive substitution yields $F(X) = P(X\le X) = 1$ which is nonsense. Solution: don't think about it too much. The substitution is incoherent, using $X$ in a two different senses.  Just remember that $F(x)$ defines a function, as in a real valued function you can plot. And then $F(X)$ is the random variable you'd get by running every realization of $X$ through that function $F$. (If you want to "think too much" about why the substitution is incoherent: recall a random variable $X$ is a function on the sample space. The RHS of the expression for the CDF $F(x) = P(X\le x)$ is a *functional*, not a function of $X$.)

In fact, far from being nonsense, $F(X)$ is has quite a nice interpretation. Recall you can interpret $F(x)$ as the quantile. In other words, you plug in $x$ and get out what quantile $x$ is of the distribution of $X$. This is pretty much just the definition. Thus $F(X)$ is just what quantile $X$ happened to land on. A little thought reveals that for a continuous RV, this must be a uniform random variable. Loose proof: Let $U=F(X)$ then $$ P(U\le u) = P(F(X)\le u) = P(X\le F^{-1}(u)) = F(F^{-1}(u)) = u$$ (Looks good, but did I sweep under the rug here? And why did I say $X$ needs to be a continuous RV?)

If $Y = e^{F(X)}$ you can do a computation of the CDF of $Y$ along the same lines as for $U=F(X)$ above.